# How to get values of selected range with right click in wx.grid in wxpython?

Tags: python, grid, wxpython, selected

I can get value of a single selected cell with right click in wx.grid this way, when i right click on a cell, it prints value of that cell:

```
self.Bind(wx.grid.EVT_GRID_CELL_RIGHT_CLICK , self.OnSelectCell, self.mygrid)    
def OnSelectCell(self, event):
   row = event.GetRow()
   column = event.GetCol()
   print self.mygrid.GetCellValue(row,column) 
   event.Skip()
```

But I couldn't find out how to get all values in a selected range with right click, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like getting selected cells in the grid is actually more complicated than I thought. Fortunately, someone has already written up some code explaining it all here:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20200214005240/http://ginstrom.com/scribbles/2008/09/07/getting-the-selected-cells-from-a-wxpython-grid/

There are 3 ways of selecting cells in a grid, so there are 3 different ways of acquiring the selection.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I bind that function to a context menu item?

Comment: The wxPython demo has a PopupMenu demo. Create the menu and bind EVT_MENU to the function in the link supplied in the answer. You'll probably need to bind EVT_CONTEXT_MENU to popup the menu itself.

Comment: note for future searchers - I found that if you want the context menu to appear in a grid, you have to bind to wx.grid.EVT_GRID_CELL_RIGHT_CLICK rather than an actual menu event.

Comment: The link is dead, alas!

Comment: Drat! Sorry about that. I should have copied that code into my answer

Comment: Fortunately the link got archived latest in november 2020 on the internet archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20200214005240/http://ginstrom.com/scribbles/2008/09/07/getting-the-selected-cells-from-a-wxpython-grid/ @MikeDriscoll if you want to update your answer with the archive link